# mysql crash windows aio cannot continue operation

Tags: mysql, windows, crash, wamp, aio

today my installation of mysql 5.5.20 wamp has been randomly crashing.

seems like it fails at 
InnoDB: File operation call: 'Windows aio'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.

i have run `mysqlcheck -c  -u root -p --all-databases` ,  and everything turns up OK.

what can i do to trouble shoot this issue ? i am running windows server 2008

## error dump is below

```
Version: '5.5.20-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
160726 22:15:28  InnoDB: Operating system error number 6 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name .\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'Windows aio'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
160726 22:16:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160726 22:16:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160726 22:16:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
160726 22:16:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160726 22:16:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 512.0M
160726 22:16:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160726 22:16:01 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 167955104047
160726 22:16:01  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 167960346624
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 167965589504
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 167965777961
160726 22:16:04  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 12509012, file name .\mysql-bin.000297
160726 22:16:08  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160726 22:16:09 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 167965777961
160726 22:16:09 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
160726 22:16:09 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
160726 22:16:09 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
160726 22:16:10 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160726 22:16:10 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.20-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: What were you doing just before it crashed? This does not tell us anything other than MYSQL Seems to be able to recover that database quite happily.

Comment: When was the last time you did a database backup? You seem to have a lot of binlog files `mysql-bin.000297`

Comment: i have been running the same task for 2-3 years now on the same platform,  only in the last 2 days mysql process crashes approximately once per hour.     i keep the binlog files for 7 days,  and we do a full backup of the database daily.      it is hosted on a windows virtual server node,  how can we determine if it is some sync process or virus scan which the node is running without my knowledge ?

Comment: Check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239668/fails-to-initialize-mysql-database-on-windows-10/48539956#answer-48539956