# Fails to initialize MySQL database on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, docker, laradock

Using [Laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock)

System Info:

- Docker version: 17.10.0-ce, build f4ffd25
- OS: Windows 10 Home

When I run `docker-compose up -d mysql` I'm getting error. Following is the docker logs

> [Note] Basedir set to /usr/
>
> [Warning] The syntax '--symbolic-links/-s' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
>
> [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
>
> [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
>
> [ERROR] Aborting

I have tried deleting `mysql` folder under `~/.laradock\data` and didn't work.

**Update 1**

**MySQL Container under laradock Dockerfile**

```
mysql:
  build:
    context: ./mysql
    args:
      - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
  volumes:
    - ${DATA_SAVE_PATH}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  ports:
    - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
  networks:
    - backend
```

**MySQL Dockerfile**

```
ARG MYSQL_VERSION=8.0
FROM mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}

MAINTAINER Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>

#####################################
# Set Timezone
#####################################

ARG TZ=UTC
ENV TZ ${TZ}
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/

ADD my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf

CMD ["mysqld"]

EXPOSE 3306
```

**Update 2**

After I delete `mysql` folder under `~/.laradock/data` I'm getting following error. After the command it generates the files in below image. When I rerun giving back the previous error mentioned above.

> [Note] Basedir set to /usr/
>
> [Warning] The syntax '--symbolic-links/-s' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
>
> [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
>
> [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
>
> [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --log-slave-updates work.
>
> libnuma: Warning: /sys not mounted or invalid. Assuming one node: No such file or directory
> mbind: Operation not permitted
>
> [ERROR]
> InnoDB: Operating system error number 22 in a file operation.
>
> [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 22 means
> 'Invalid argument'
>
> [ERROR] InnoDB: File
> ./ib_logfile101: 'aio write' returned OS error 122. Cannot continue
> operation
>
> [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot
> continue operation.

[image]

** I tried in a windows 7 machine and its working.

Comment: We need at least the `mysql:` section of the docker-compose.yml

Comment: @Robert Added to the question

Comment: Are you sure that you have this dir empty? `~/.laradock/data/mysql`, you've put '\data` in the question, instead of `/data`

Comment: @Robert Yes I deleted the directory. I updated the question with new logs. Please check. Thanks

Comment: On Windows 10, are you using Docker for Windows (the "new" way) or an old way using Docker Toolbox? If former, are you setting it to run Linux containers and not Windows containers? I ask because the missing /sys mount, and the combination of error codes in your Update 2 section.

Comment: @bluescores I'm using Docker toolbox. Where/ How do I set to to run for windows containers?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Disable AIO

This fixed it for me when I got the AIO error as you did when I was starting a container from a guest Debian OS from Virtualbox and creating the database files on a shared folder on Windows 10.

The issue seems to be that AIO is not supported on shared folders, or at least on some versions of Windows. It seems to have occurred for me after I moved from Windows 10 Pro to Home after my main machine crashed.

For details:

- [aio](http://lse.sourceforge.net/io/aio.html)
- [disable aio in MySQL for zfs](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/57)

Here are some options:

**Option 1 - start the container like this :**

```
docker run -it mysql --innodb_use_native_aio=0
```

**Option 2 - add the command to your docker-compose file:**

```
 command: --innodb_use_native_aio=0
```

In context, this is the relevant portion of my working docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
   db:
     image: ${MYSQL_IMAGE}
     command: "--innodb_use_native_aio=0"
     volumes:
       - ${DB_DATA_PATH}:/var/lib/mysql
     ports:
        - ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306
```

**Option 3 -- add an option to your my.cnf file in your build**

```
innodb_use_native_aio=0
```

**Option 4 - Don't persist  your DB on the local file system.(Can destroy your db, Not Recommended)**

Simply remove the volume in your docker configuration that contains your mysql db. Of course, your DB will be deleted if you do a docker-compose down or otherwise destroy your container, so there's that.

Comment: note too, that you may need to empty out your ${DATA_SAVE_PATH} after you fix the AIO issue. Otherwise, mysql may refuse to initialize a data path with files in it.

Comment: According to documentation, command line option is expected to be `--innodb-use-native-aio=0`. Correct or both works equally?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but Try this step.This is because of data folder.

Try remove the docker image. List all images using **docker images** then remove the mysql & laradock mysql using **docker rmi imagename**. Dont forget remove the docker volume using **docker volume rm volumename**
Also go to **cd ~/.laradock/data** remove the mysql folder.

Then try **docker-compose up mysql** for debuging. If no errors, you could try **docker-compose up -d mysql**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my Windows 10 Enterprise, I couldn't find perfect solution around it because it seems to be my Windows version issue - I have ran the same image on other windows (8 & 10 professional) successfully. My temporary work around was to remove the /var/lib/mysql mount entirely from the docker-compose file allowing the database data files to be created and modified in the container itself.

I use kitematics which will restart and reattach my created container anytime I want to work on the container, like that I don't loose my data when the container exit. If you don't use kitematics this what it does.
After running docker-compose the image will be created and a container will be created to run it as well, I avoid using run on the created image because this will create new container
I stick to running the following sequentially

```
docker ps -a                 # this command will get container_id of all container, those that are running and those that are not
docker start <container_id>  # start container from background
docker attach <container_id> # attach container to standard input
```

With these docker commands my data were preserved in the container even after exiting and restarting

### BACK UP

Now whenever I want to move the data, I will commit my container into an image and save the image to local storage

```
docker commit <container_id> <backup_image_name>:<1_31_2017> # I use date to tag it
docker save -o <local_storage_tar_name> <backup_image_name>
```

### RESTORE

Whenever I need to restore the mysql container either on my computer or for a new programming intern

```
cd <dir_containing_the_tar_file>
docker load -o <local_storage_tar_name>
```

This solution is for your update

```
 File ./ib_logfile101: 'aio write' returned OS error 122. Cannot continue operation
```

I hope this helps somebody

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try and let you know later

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the response above by [AndrewD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3306354/andrewd), you should change the permission on the `my.cnf` so that it does not get ignored when booting up. You can run the below command,

```sh
sudo chmod 400 my.cnf
```

Do this right before running `docker-compose up -d`