# How to set up docker-compose to initialize MySQL database on Windows 10?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm attempting to create a MySQL database (on a Docker container, with docker toolbox on a Windows 10 host) using docker-compose with this configuration:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: test
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mydb'
    ports: 
      - 6612:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
```

I run this in a folder that only contains the `docker-compose.yml` and get the following output.

```
$ docker-compose up

Recreating test ... done
Attaching to test
test  | Initializing database
test  | 2018-04-21T17:31:30.722810Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
test  | 2018-04-21T17:31:30.727269Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
test  | 2018-04-21T17:31:30.727618Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
test  |
test  | Initializing database
test  | 2018-04-21T17:31:30.722810Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit 
      .
      .
      .
```

It seems to be complaining about files existing but how could there when the folder is empty?

Second time I run the same file, in the same empty (apart from `docker-compose.yml`) I get:

```
Starting test ... done
Attaching to test
test  | Initializing database
test  | 2018-04-21T17:36:12.716214Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
test  | 2018-04-21T17:36:12.726611Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
test  | 2018-04-21T17:36:13.466867Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 22 in a file operation.
test  | 2018-04-21T17:36:13.467174Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 22 means 'Invalid argument'
test  | 2018-04-21T17:36:13.467475Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File ./ib_logfile101: 'aio write' returned OS error 122. Cannot continue operation
test  | 2018-04-21T17:36:13.467649Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
test exited with code 1
```

This time it creates the a `./db` folder in my pwd with a few files:

- ib_logfile1
- ib_logfile101
- ibdata1

But nothing more, and running it again we are back to the first output. The same `docker-compose.yml` works without a hitch on Ubuntu 16.04. Could anyone advise me what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the key was in in this output line:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: File ./ib_logfile101: 'aio write' returned OS error 122.
```

Apparently having AIO enabled doesn't work with my set up. I'm still not sure why but this revised `docker-compose.yml` works for me:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: test
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --innodb_use_native_aio=0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mydb'
    ports: 
      - 6612:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Found this thanks to AndrewD's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48631919/2671179) still not sure what exactly is the problem. Though I suspect Docker Toolbox (as opposed to Docker for Windows) might have something to do with it.

Comment: It does not work for me, but I have the error `File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71.`